# Cannot delete record from rails console in AWS eb cli if a wrong subclass value is specified for a STI parent class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, activerecord, sti

A colleague added a new record for the class "Production" via our `rails admin` interface, which is the parent class via STI of the subclass "CoProduction".

The `type` attribute was by mistake filled out via the `rails_admin` with a value that is not the specified subclass "CoProduction", but with a wrong one. As a result I cannot delete nor update the record from rails console in our AWS environment (and the `rails admin` interface has crashed and is not starting over again either).

```
[1] pry(main)> Production.last
  Production Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "productions".* FROM "productions" ORDER BY "productions"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

> ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: The single-table inheritance mechanism
> failed to locate the subclass: 'opera buffa'. This error is raised
> because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of
> inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be
> used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite
> Production.inheritance_column to use another column for that
> information.

#### EDIT

I could solve the issue meanwhile, by connecting via PGADMIN to the db instance,retrieving the culprit record and modify it. Unfortunately this error was not to be solved in an ActiveRecord environment

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the record was somehow added by skipping the default validation defined for STI. You can follow the same way to recover the record and set its proper type by using:

[`ActiveRecord::Relation#update_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all), which **neither instantiates the involved models nor triggers Active Record callbacks/validations**.

In rails console, find all occurrences of wrong types (e.g. `opera buffa`) in `Production` model and update it to type `CoProduction`:

```
Production.where(type: 'opera buffa').update_all(type: 'CoProduction')
```

`Production` model should work as usual after this point.

Comment: hallo thanks, unfortunately Rails Console did not allow me to perform any similar action...I could solve the issue in the meantime :)

Answer (score -1):

I could solve the issue meanwhile, by connecting via PGADMIN to the db instance,retrieving the culprit record and modify it. Unfortunately this error was not to be solved in an ActiveRecord environment

Comment: this can definitely be solved by ActiveRecord. Please check my answer and let me know the issues you faced. Thanks

Comment: Hi thanks, I should reproduce the error, now it is not there anymore. The issues were already explained.

Comment: Please remove the downvote to my solution, which actually did solve the issue. The solution provided by Wasif didnt work , I already tried that before posting the question here. Whenever I tried to update it would trigger the above activerecord error.